# Accessing a value in a method using *

Tags: ruby, methods

In a method definition, when `*` is used in the following manner, what does it mean?

```
def foo(*)
   ...
end
```

I understand the following usage:

```
def foo(*args)
   ...
end
```

I am not sure how I will access the method params in the former case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "take and discard any number of parameters".

Both definitions are technically the same, but not giving a name to the argument array means you can't access it.

Comment: What happens if you call `super`?

Comment: I kind of guessed it but could not determine if there is any specific use of it and why not just use methods without any params.

Comment: @dasil003, in that case the parameters are not discarded but forwarded to the next method in the chain. By discarded I mean that the argument array isn't bound to a local variable, and thus can't be accessed. Ruby still holds an internal reference to it.

Comment: I figured, but I thought I'd ask just for completeness :), +1

Comment: @Prasad, don't forget to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)!

Answer (score 0):

In the first case it just allows calling with arbitrary arguments and discards them.

The second case assigns any called arguments to args