# Ruby method arguments with just * operator: def save(*) .. end

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [naked asterisk as parameter in method definition: def f(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249537/naked-asterisk-as-parameter-in-method-definition-def-f)
>   [Accessing a value in a method using *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641489/accessing-a-value-in-a-method-using)

The [save(*)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) method in Rails takes just a single asterisk as an argument.

I know that `*` can be used for variable length arguments as in `*args`, but what does the `*` mean in this context? How does one access the arguments here?

And more specifically, how would one pass all the arguments on to a `super` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, `save` doesn't take any arguments. That's what happens with a naked splat. But, as you may be aware, calling `save` on an ActiveRecord model accepts options because this method gets overridden by `ActiveRecord::Validations` here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb#L47

```
# The validation process on save can be skipped by passing <tt>:validate => false</tt>. The regular Base#save method is
# replaced with this when the validations module is mixed in, which it is by default.
def save(options={})
  perform_validations(options) ? super : false
end
```

Comment: So it's called a [naked splat](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/). Interesting.

Comment: @ZahanM Well, the asterisk is considered the "splat operator" in Ruby. The "naked" part I just made up, so I would hesitate to consider that a ubiquitous name for it. That said, it's unlikely to be mistaken for anything else Ruby-related, so I think it's safe to use. :)